# Facebook not showing photos on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-photos, facebook-events

We have recently held an event and upload the photos to the event page. People can tag themselves in them but the photos are not showing up on the individual's timeline. The event and photos are both public as well as the photos appearing on the activity log as 'allowed on timeline' but they are not appearing. Can anybody help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, photos tagged in groups and events do not surface in the user's timeline. (I've tested it)

The user should however get a notification that he/she was tagged.